# Python / SQLalchemy - how to trigger a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working at getting SQLalchemy to do some tasks for me via python.

I can sort of get it working by following examples, but I have been stuck for a while now on moving the query call from a `for` loop:

```
for instance in session.query(versions_table).filter(versions_table.c.version==Version):
```

and getting result by calling one of the table results:

```
 existingID = instance.id
```

(where `id` is the PK for the returning table)

What I can't do is finding a way of firing the query at will, or as a result of a conditional statement, e.g.

```
if some conditions met:
 do query
 get / process result
```

I can only get the returned values by calling `instance.fieldname`

Could anyone point me to where I am going wrong, accepting that I'm not really 100% comfortable with how the SQLalchemy  functions are setup/called.

What I want to do is along the lines of:

```
for instance in session.query(versions_table).filter(versions_table.c.version==Version):
 if instance.id == True:  #this is not correct
  print instance.id 
 else:
  print "no match"
```

fuller script:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://u:p@localhost/sqlalchtest',
                   echo=False)

metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
versions_table = Table('versions', metadata, autoload=True)

def doVersionGet(sigfile_filename):
 tree = etree.parse(sigfile_filename)
 root = tree.getroot()
 attributes = root.attrib
 if 'DateCreated' in root.attrib:
  DateCreated = (attributes["DateCreated"])
 if 'Version' in root.attrib:
  Version = (attributes["Version"])
 doVersionPush(DateCreated,Version)

def doVersionPush(DateCreated,Version):
 session = Session() 
 for instance in session.query(versions_table).filter(versions_table.c.version==Version):
  existingID = instance.id 
  #this is not really what I want to do here any way, but this will fire the query every time

if __name__ == "__main__":
 path = "location\sub_sig_files"  ##home_subset for tests
 for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
  for file in files:
   sigfile_filename = str(path)+"\\"+str(file)
   doVersionGet(sigfile_filename)
```

Comment: Why do you need to force the query to run, if you're not actually using the result?

Comment: I am simply trying to get it to fire when I want, and decouple it from the `for` loop - I included the code to show how I had found a method `instance.fieldname` that does something.

Comment: Okay, to rephrase: why do you need it to "fire when you want"? SQLAlchemy evaluates queries lazily - that is, it waits to evaluate them until you actually *do* something with their results (which generally makes sense, because it means that if you don't actually need the results, you can save the time from running the query in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I edited the OP to show what I want to do - does that make it clearer? What I don't know how to do is to decouple from the `for` so I can't find a way of simply passing it a variable and calling it - I'm a bit confused by how its getting triggered, and furthermore how to evaluate the result, (i.e. how to get a True/False outcome).

Comment: Fyi, one-space indentation is horrible to read.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks, but - I have no idea how else to get it to tag properly - its a pain to do too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute the query with [`Query.all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=query#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all), which will execute the query and return the instances:

```
instances = session.query(versions_table).filter(versions_table.c.version==Version).all()
```

Comment: Ah, yes! thank you. With your help, and @Amber's pointed questions I have got it doing what I want. Thank you. I really appreciate your time.